# Product name, title and price are missing when a product is accessed through SOAP web service in Magento 1.4.2.0

Tags: php, magento, soap

This is the response that I am getting in the console:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [sku] => PPS-S
            [set] => 4
            [type] => simple
            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                    [1] => 169
                    [2] => 256
                    [3] => 257
                )

            [websites] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: what you are doing specifically to get this would probably be helpful

Comment: I am trying to get entire details of a product through php client for Magento

Comment: which API function are you using to get this output ?

Comment: this is the function that I am using `getCatalogProductList`

Comment: It seems like this function is not supported in Magento 1.4.2.0